# Moving packages in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

I have a problem moving packages in IntelliJ IDEA. I have created Maven project with multiple modules and each of those modules has a package with the same name. Now whole project becomes a mess if I try to rename some of the packages.

My current project structure is something like this:

```
--parent-module
  |
  |--module-one
  |  |--src
  |     |--main
  |        |--java
  |           |--somepackage
  |              |--someotherpackages
  |--module-two
  |  |--src
  |     |--main
  |        |--java
  |           |--somepackage
  |              |--somemorepackages
  |--module-three
     |--src
        |--main
           |--java
              |--somepackage
                 |--someevenmorepackages
```

Notice that *somepackage* is present in all maven modules.

After **MANY** created classes in all of those modules and packages I have finally realised what have I done. Now I need to put *somepackage* into another package under java so I can have something like *com.example.moduleone.somepackage*.

I have tried renaming package but it renames it in all modules and that creates hailstorm of errors in the code. Also, IntelliJ IDEA renames it to *com.example.**moduleone**.somepackage* in all of the modules.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Might be easiest to create the new package first and then move the classes you want to move into it and then delete somepackage once everything have been moved around

So first add moduleone, then move all of the classes you want to move, then do the same for the other modules, then delete somepackage

Comment: Already tried that, but if I try to move the package to the moduleone package it moves it in all of the modules (creates com.example.moduleone.somepackage in all modules).

Comment: In the end I have done it by creating new packages with the same structure but under *com.example.moduleone* and moved all classes in the corresponding new packages. A lot of manual work (select all classes in old package and drag to the new package) but beats fixing million errors. Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 0):

1. Right click to `Project name` > `New`> `Module..`> chose java version and set name for new module.
2. Drag your packpage your want move to `new-module/src` > `OK` > `Refactor`.
3. Rebuild project. Find erro : java: packpage dose not exist. Fix it by: Go to erro code > `Atl`+`Enter` > `Add depedency on module..`